# list item data lost after loading another component react

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and trying to build a simple app using react and firebase.

I have the parent class Homepage.js where I place the my other component HomePageRecipe.js like this:

```
<HomePageRecipe changeToRecipes={this.showRecipes.bind(this)} />
```

In my HomePageRecipe I have a function called `componentDidMount` where I get the firebase data. Here is the function:

```
componentDidMount(){

   let recipePath = "/recipe";

       firebase.database().ref(recipePath).on('child_added', (snapshot) => {

            this.setState({title: snapshot.val().title});
            this.setState({recipeKey: snapshot.key});

            this.setState({previousKeys: [...this.state.recipeKeys, this.state.recipeKey]});
            this.setState({previousList: [...this.state.titleForRecipeList, this.state.title]});

           this.setState({titleForRecipeList: this.state.previousList});
           this.setState({recipeKeys: this.state.previousKeys});

   });
```

}

My problem appear when I added the third component. In this I choose not to show the HomePage.js with the HomePageRecipe.js inside. When i get back to the HomePage.js component with the HomePageRecipe.js component inside the function `componentDidMount()` isn't called again, how can i call it? or is there a kind of update function? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you make a codesandbox? or codepen... You need to not chain all those setStates like that. The last 2 setStates you're calling are the problem. You need to call them as one setState either outside of the DidMount lifecycle method or in the callback of the first setState... something like: ```this.setState({first bunch}, this.setState({last 2 }))``` This is just a guess mind you... which is why i didn't post an answer... i only suspect this is the issue.

Comment: I just made one on https://codesandbox.io/ with the title 24nwp54l7n hope you can see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
componentDidMount() {

    let recipePath = "/recipe";

    var self = this;
    firebase.database().ref(recipePath).once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(x => {


            self.setState({title: x.val().title});
            self.setState({recipeKey: x.key});

            self.setState({previousKeys: [...self.state.recipeKeys, self.state.recipeKey]});
            self.setState({previousList: [...self.state.titleForRecipeList, self.state.title]});

            self.setState({titleForRecipeList: self.state.previousList});
            self.setState({recipeKeys: self.state.previousKeys});
        });
    });

}
```